# How to get the itself path for an Automator application?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm creating an Application in Mac Automator (MacOs Catalina) that creates a file in the same directory where the .app is.
To get the .app path I'm using:

- for apple script: `POSIX path of (path to me)`
- for javascript: `app.pathTo(this).toString()`

It is works great...
... until send the .app to someone in internet.

If the app was download from internet and run, it shows this error

> `/private/var/folders/.../.../...` read-only file system

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me some time to find it out, so I'm creating this Q&A.

It seems that MacOS adds the extended attribute `com.apple.quarantine` for downloaded apps. I think apps with this attribute run in some kind of sandbox.

To remove it just run:

```
$ xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine my_app.app/
```